# Generating a number based on the amount of rows in a sql table

Tags: c#

I had it working for 1 label but when i try to add the same code for the other label i can't use "GetNumber" and "noRows"

//

```
        //Populate the OrderID label

        sqlSupplierOrder = @"select * from SupplierOrder";
        daSupplierOrder = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSupplierOrder, cnstr);
        cmdBSupplierOrder = new SqlCommandBuilder(daSupplierOrder);
        daSupplierOrder.FillSchema(dsPennyburnGreg, SchemaType.Source, "SupplierOrder");
        daSupplierOrder.Fill(dsPennyburnGreg, "SupplierOrder");



        int noRows = dsPennyburnGreg.Tables["SupplierOrder"].Rows.Count;

        if (noRows == 0)
            lbl_OrderID.Text = "7000";
        else
        {
            GetNumber(noRows);
        }


        int noRows = dsPennyburnGreg.Tables["Payment"].Rows.Count;

        if (noRows == 0)
            lbl_PaymentRef.Text = "8000";
        else
        {
            GetNumber(noRows);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please explain your problem more in detail

Comment: Remove the int type from the second set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `noRows` twice. Remove the `int` from in front of the second declaration in order to reuse that variable.

Instead of using `GetNumber`, why not just use `Rows.Count` like you are in your `if` statement?